# using recordset in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, recordset

I am trying to fetch data from database using recordset with following code in classic ASP .I am using windows 7 32 bit OS:

```
<%
dim con,rs
set con=Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
con.Open "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\New folder\123.mdb"
rs.Open "select * from student",con
for each x in rs.fields
response.write(x.name)
response.write("=")
response.write(x.value)
next
rs.Close
con.Close
%>
```

error is:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: ''

/New folder/recordset.asp, line 7
```

Comment: First you have ta make a recordset object <% dim con,rs set con=Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset") con.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" con.Open "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\New folder\123.mdb" set rs=Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset") rs.Open "student",con while NOT rs.EOF Response.write(rs("name")&"="&rs("value") rs.MoveNext Wend rs.Close con.Close set rs=nothing
%>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word "rs" is not reserved in VBScript, you must create a recordset yourself.

Change the line:

```
rs.Open "select * from student",con
```

To this instead:

```
Set rs = con.Execute("select * from student")
```

You also iterate only the first record, to iterate all records change the code to:

```
Do Until rs.EOF
    for each x in rs.fields
        response.write(x.name)
        response.write("=")
        response.write(x.value)
        response.write(", ")
    next
    response.write("<br />")
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```